# Regex Option - no recursive regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` class to grab some text from a JSON string. The sting is something like

```
[{"name":"joe","message":"hello","sent":"datetime"}{"name":"steve","message":"bye","sent":"datetime"}]
```

I'm attempting to use the Matches() method to grab the "message" values. However, specifying a match as something like `message":"*","sent` as the pattern would return 3 matches:

```
hello
bye
hello","sent":"datetime"}{"name":"steve","message":"bye
```

How do I structure the options or modify my pattern to exclude recursive regex checks? I only want matches

```
hello
bye
```

Comment: You may want to address why you're using a RegEx instead of one of the numerous tried-and-true JSON libraries and snippets available in C#.

Comment: I would recommend using JSON.NET, this is not a good application for RegEx. You can download the package through NuGet in Visual Studio or it can be found here; http://nuget.org/packages?q=Json.NET

Comment: Is that really the regex you used? I don't see how it would return those matches. Should `*` have been `.*`?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScriptSerializer class (namespace System.Web.Script.Serialization, assembly System.Web.Extensions.dll) is pretty useful for dealing with JSON strings like this.

```
var json = "[{\"name\":\"joe\",\"message\":\"hello\",\"sent\":\"datetime\"},{\"name\":\"steve\",\"message\":\"bye\",\"sent\":\"datetime\"}]";

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = serializer.Deserialize<object[]>(json);

// now have an array of objects, each of which happens to be an IDictionary<string, object>
foreach(IDictionary<string, object> map in result)
{
    var messageValue = map["message"].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("message = {0}", messageValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON is better parsed by a JSON tool.

You can try using the non-greedy syntax `.*?` for example.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use the Json.net DeserializeObject method - Here is what I have so far:
string[] messages = new string[NumberOfMessages];
            for(int i = 0; i < messages.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            {
                messages[i] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(;
            }

Comment: Note sure how to structure the <>() after DeserializeObject for a string... Thanks you everyone for their input!

Comment: @Zach: I would recommend posting another question if you want to know about how to use a Json tool.